# Total ordered set

Tags: analysis

I am not sure whether the relation $\leq$ for set $M=\{{f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}}$: f Function} is a total ordered set, for $\leq$ is defined as: $ f \leq g : \leftrightarrow \forall x \in \mathbb{R}: f(x) \leq g(x)$.
I have already shown that it is a partial order and I'm not sure how to proof that it is a total ordered set or not. Is there someone who can help me, please?

Comment: Check $f(x)=\sin x$, $g(x)=\cos x$.

Comment: You could use step functions to create a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A set $S$ with a relation $\leq$ is classified as a total order if any two elements are comparable. That is, for $a, b \in S$, either $a \leq b$ or $b \leq a$.

In your example, notice that for $f \leq g$, the requirement is that $$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \ f(x) \leq g(x)$$

The $\forall x$ is what prevents this from being a total order: an easy way to see this is to pick functions that "cross over" at some point. That is, pick a pair of functions where

$$
f(x) \leq g(x) \in R_1
$$

And $$g(x) \leq f(x) \in R_2$$

Such functions will be non-comparable.

#### Counterexamples

1. $\sin x$, $\cos x$. These peridocally cross over an infinite number
   of times over $\mathbb{R}$
2. $f(x) = x$, $g(x) = x^2$. Here, $f(x) \leq g(x) \in [-\infty, 1]$ and $g(x) \leq f(x) \in [1, \infty]$